# Jquery count next class, after clicked current class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after click on each `Click Me` count next class `.ChIdx`.

**EX:**
If click on `Click Me` Num 2 result is : 2
If click on `Click Me` Num 3 result is : 1
If click on `Click Me` Num 1 result is : 3
If click on `Click Me` Num 4 result is : 0
Etc...

How is it, what do i do?

i tried following code but don't work:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5nubs4k6/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.NextCount', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var SizNext = $(this).closest('.ChIdx').next('.ChIdx').size();
    alert(SizNext)
})
```

```css
.NextCount{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ChIdx">
    <span class="NextCount">Click Me</span> // Num 1
</div>
<div class="ChIdx">
    <span class="NextCount">Click Me</span> // Num 2
</div>
<div class="ChIdx">
    <span class="NextCount">Click Me</span> // Num 3
</div>
<div class="ChIdx">
    <span class="NextCount">Click Me</span> // Num 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.next` use [.nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.NextCount', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var SizNext = $(this).closest('.ChIdx').nextAll('.ChIdx').size();
    alert(SizNext)
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5nubs4k6/1/)

**Update:**

Instead of [.size](http://api.jquery.com/size/) use `.length`, because .size is deprecated. Thanks **@A. Wolff** for this advice.

Comment: ***as a side note*** use `length` instead of `size()` which is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of the index, passed in the callback and just attach handler to `ChIdx`

```
$('.ChIdx').click(function(e){
    alert("Num" + ($(this).index() + 1));
});
```